# Android press Button cannot appear Webview program troubleshooting

Tags: android

I implemented the the Android webview encounter some problem
Beginning do a OptionMenu, and he will appear when you press the Menu four locations
I use the mouse click taipei he displayed to Toast
But I would like to implement the functionality Toast message screen webview display the specified web page
I use Intent a = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse ();
 startActivity (a);
Can successfully display the webpage
But I would like to the webview implement web pages using setContentView ();
Switch to taipei.xml <= webview, when I click on the submit button, it could not display the webpage using webview
Please help me to see where the problems lie, because beginners just learning, I hope to try to attach the code to solve my problem.
Code URL: [I implemented the the Android webview encounter some problem
Beginning do a OptionMenu, and he will appear when you press the Menu four locations
I use the mouse click taipei he displayed to Toast
But I would like to implement the functionality Toast message screen webview display the specified web page
I use Intent a = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse ("http://www.taipei-101.com.tw/"));
 startActivity (a);
Can successfully display the webpage
But I would like to the webview implement web pages using setContentView ();
Switch to taipei.xml <= webview, when I click on the submit button, it could not display the webpage using webview
Please help me to see where the problems lie, because beginners just learning, I hope to try to attach the code to solve my problem.

Code URL: http://www.javaworld.com.tw/jute/post/view?bid=26&id=312960&sty=1#312960
And attach performed on screen picture

And attach performed on screen picture in the cod URL
Implore help thank you